# Is there a way to add column Name in csv file from copydata activity in datafactory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have to pick a csv file from a filesystem folder and put it into a storage account folder. I need to add the name of the column to the csv file when copying it into the storage because after I must use anohter standard pipeline which need the columnname in the file.
Is it possible to do it in  datafactory or i should try to use other services?

Comment: Do you mean you want add one header as a column in csv file? In Azure Data Factory, can you try additional column in Copy Activity?

Comment: I mean I don't have the headers in my source file  and i want to add it. Sorry if I explained myself badly.

Comment: Where are the headers from?

Comment: I want to add them, in the source folder i have a csv file like:
3323423;gigio;cefefee;2222
2222222;pippo;cccccc;3333

I want to put in my sink folder the same file but with a header, then I want to add a row at the top:
id;name;piva;codice
3323423;gigio;cefefee;2222
2222222;pippo;cccccc;3333

An use that first row as header in another pipeline to laod the file into an sql db. I want to add the headers, there is not one .

Comment: I think you should use dataflow to merge these csv files(one with headers and others with content).

Comment: Ok thanks, i will probably do that.

Answer (score 1):

In ADF, you can add a column in Copy Activity via **additional column**.

You can key in the name and value, the result is as follows:
[image]